# Docker-compose.yml for NodeJs with MySQL on AWS Elastic Beanstalk single container Docker

Tags: mysql, node.js, deployment, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Nodejs app that is hosted on AWS EB Single container Docker. I connect to MySQL database from the app.
For now I am deploying my app from AWS console by uploading zip file. Everything is working as expected. 
I would like to be able to push changes to AWS using CLI. 
It's my understanding that I need docker-compose.yml file to accomplish that. I have seen samples of docker-compose file that creates two containers one for node, another for mysql. 
Is there a way to user docker-compose.yml and still deploy to a single container Docker?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can deploy a docker-compose file to Elastic Beanstalk. But, I can think of two ways for deploying your code from the command line:

One is to put your existing zip file in an s3 bucket (which can be scripted) and then to use the Elastic Beanstalk command line something like this:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name avengers \
    --version-label v1 \
    --source-bundle S3Bucket="avengers-docker-eb",S3Key="deployment.zip" \
    --auto-create-application \
    --region eu-west-3
```

The full instructions are here: https://read.acloud.guru/docker-on-elastic-beanstalk-tips-e1a4e6b70ff2

The second way, and the one you might prefer is to create a Dockerrun.aws.json file that points to your docker image either in an s3 bucket or in a docker registry (you can use the aws one). From there you can update your application from the cli like so:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --application-name [your_app_name] --environment-name [your_environment_name] --version-label [your_version_label]
```

The pertinent documentation is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker.html

Y

Comment: Second way sounds very appealing to me. Thanks a lot